# SSD monitoring software for OS X

Tags: osx, system-monitor, ssd

After installing SSD to my Macbook Pro, I want to monitor its usage.

- **Must:** Show average data written per day
- **Must:** Record that data
- **Should:** Estimate lifespan of disk

Comment: It's different than HDD ones?

Comment: @Braiam yes, because of the lifespan

Comment: What's the difference between must and should?

Comment: I don't know, ask the editor ( @Oxinabox )

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MoSCoW_method

Dirty-flow: Feel free to edit it all to be Must if that is what you want. I interpretted the final requirement as more of a Should than a Must, but it could be a Could have.
It is a bit of a Should to me, as you can use the earlier data to do some looking up yourself -- so there are work arounds.

Comment: @Oxinabox Thanks for the link! And I had no idea there was an RFC just on that topic: [RFC 2119](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt).

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [SSD Health monitor?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4993862) DriveDx is quite popular, although it is only a 10 day free trail though, so it is not free.

> Check out [DriveDx](http://binaryfruit.com/drivedx). It shows SSD
>   Lifetime Left indicator, overall health rating, important health
>   indicators and many other useful information about SSD. With clean and
>   user-friendly Mac-style interface. (HDDs are supported too)

This question has also been asked on SE AskDifferent: [Is there a utility for mac that shows the information of an SSD like the health etc…?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70425/is-there-a-utility-for-mac-that-shows-the-information-of-an-ssd-like-the-health). One answer suggests a free tool, [`smartmontools`](http://www.smartmontools.org/). However, it does require some coding using Xcode, unless you use the macports port (`port install smartmontools`)